# How to download the latest jar file from GitHub packages and deploy to cloud hub using Maven GitHub actions?

Tags: java, maven, github-actions, mule4

I have created a GitHub package and created releases with GitHub actions for a simple Hello-world mule application.

```
name: GitHub Packages and Releases using Java CI with Maven
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 11
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
      
    
  Publish:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '11'

      - name: Create GitHub Release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GIT_TOKEN}} 
        with: 
          tag_name: v${{github.run_number}}
```

Now I wanted to download the jar file from the GitHub package or extract zip folder (source code.zip) from Releases and deploy the jar file to cloud hub using Maven GitHub actions.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think that you can't reuse the filesystem between separate jobs, but you could create a composite action that would retain the files generated in the `build` step so they are usable later on for the `release`

Comment: @davidgamero Thanks for your response. Can we pick the latest jar from github packages and deploy to Production Environment on cloudhub? If yes, can you please let me know how to pick through maven github actions?

Comment: you might be able to just add a step that runs `mvn clean package deploy -DmuleDeploy` if you add your authentication for pushing the package if that's what you mean. I'm not sure if that will push a .jar

Comment: https://github.com/Sushma-GitRepo/Latest_Deploy/packages/1068097  --- Here is the jar  file in packages(right side), I want to deploy this jar through github actions

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Mule Maven plugin to publish an existing jar to CloudHub. It only supports publishing what's being built with Maven. You can use instead [Anypoint CLI](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/anypoint-platform-cli). For example with the [command](http://runtime-mgr%20cloudhub-application%20deploy) `runtime-mgr cloudhub-application deploy` you can deploy a jar file to CloudHub.

Comment: Thanks @aled. But for CI/CD, we build the artifact (jar file) and deploy to cloudhub using github actions, similarly, I am looking for to download the jar file from github packages and deploy to cloudhub using github actions. any possibility?

Comment: Are you looking only for the method to download the release jar?

Comment: yes, I want to download the jar and create a workflow to deploy this jar file to cloudhub